# tsql coalesce with float and varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a float field which shows data as such:

```
1
1.00
3.12
3.00
```

I also have a varchar field that shows as such:

```
NA
ND 
I
```

Data is as such: Fld_N is a float and Fld_S is varchar

```
Fld_N   Fld_S
-----   ------
1 
        ND
1.00    
3.12
3
       NA
       I
```

Notice that a row can have a value for either the Fld_N or the Fld_S but not both.

What I am doing is using the coalesce as such:

```
    COALESCE(STR(Fld_N,9,2), Fld_S)  Fld
```

This doesn't quite work well as I have the decimal points always be upto 2 decimal points whereas I need it to support showing 1 as well as 1.00. Is there a way to not specify the decimal points and still accomomdate for showing 1 and 1.00 in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the convert function:

coalesce(convert(varchar,Fld_N),Fld_S) Fdl

Answer (score 0):

In a float type column, there is absolutely no difference between `1` and `1.00`. Therefore, what you suggest is actually impossible. The data stored in your database for rows 1 and 3 are, in reality, identical.

---

However, you can cast to VARCHAR instead of using STR, which will use the least number of decimal places necessary:

```
COALESCE(CAST(fld_N AS VARCHAR(12)), Fld_S) AS Fld
```

This should produce:

```
Fld
-----
1 
ND
1    
3.12
3
NA
I
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `STR`, use

```
CAST(fld_N AS VARCHAR(9))
```

The `VARCHAR` will only use as many decimal places as necessary to show the value you provide.

Putting that into your `COALESCE` will yield:

```
COALESCE(CAST(fld_N AS VARCHAR(9)), Fld_S) AS Fld
```